# what is this semicircular crank connector part called?

Tags: connectors, adapter

The plastic hand crank handle on my compost grinder just broke, and the company that made it is long out of business.  I'm trying to see if I can find some other replacement, but I'm having trouble searching for something that would connect correctly.  The male metal part in the picture below is a semicircle 3/8" in diameter, and protruding about 7/8" out the side of the device.

I could just use a vice grips as a crank handle, but I'd like something a little more elegant.

Can you suggest some search terms that would help me find a suitable female part to match this?  I've found some oven knob replacements that talk about "D-posts", but an oven knob isn't going to give me anywhere enough leverage (and won't be strong enough).

[image: semicircular spindle]

[image: broken handle along bore hole]

Comment: exactly what broke?

Comment: The crack crosses the bore hole.  I've pressed the two broken parts together in the photgraph.

Comment: please post a picture of the two halves separated

Comment: I've posted a picture of halves seperated

Comment: You could use a window winder from a car built in the 20th century.

Comment: excellent idea, thanks!  It looks like there are a lot of "universal" window cranks that come with a variety of inserts and set-screw options, so this will probably work really well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the phrase "replacement crank handles" in google and saw lots of places to visit.
One [promising site](https://www.jwwinco.com/en-us/products/1.3-Adjusting-with-handwheels-and-cranks/Crank-handles/EN-570.2-Technopolymer-Plastic-Crank-Handles-with-Revolving-Handle-with-Blind-Bore?gf-sou=2&gf-b-rs=1&gf-b-min=7.9&gf-b-max=8&gf-l-rs=1&gf-l-min=130&gf-l-max=210#L%C3%A4nge%20l%3Dc(80)%3Bd1%3Du(221a0c08-a786-4465-afd6-a38c96e84265)) lists handles like shown here:

[image]

[Picture Source](https://www.jwwinco.com/en-us/products/1.3-Adjusting-with-handwheels-and-cranks/Crank-handles/EN-570.2-Technopolymer-Plastic-Crank-Handles-with-Revolving-Handle-with-Blind-Bore?gf-sou=2&gf-b-rs=1&gf-b-min=7.9&gf-b-max=8&gf-l-rs=1&gf-l-min=130&gf-l-max=210#L%C3%A4nge%20l%3Dc(80)%3Bd1%3Du(221a0c08-a786-4465-afd6-a38c96e84265))

A model EN 570.2-80-B3.0 sports a 3/8" bore hole and a lever length of 3.15". You may have to work out adapting the bore with a set screw or craft a D slot using epoxy.

Comment: A circular bore hole with a set screw part hadn't occurred to me.  Thanks!

Comment: Good idea on the set screw.+1

Comment: apparrently they have a steel insert, it may be possible to drill and tap them rather than messing with epoxy.